# Angular - input field value not being passed to the form submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In my Angular-15 project, I am populating a text input field with the value coming from ng-select drop down list. So I have this code:

**component.ts:**

```
import { CountryService } from 'src/app/features/admin/services/country.service';

export class CountryCreateComponent {

  countriesDatas: any[] = [];
  selectedCountryCode: string = '';
  selectedCountryName: string = '';
  createCountryForm!: FormGroup;
  showDiv: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
  }

  createCountry() {
    this.createCountryForm = this.fb.group({
      CountryCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
      CountryName: [''],
    });
  }

createValidate() {
  if (!this.createCountryForm.valid) {
    this.createCountryForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
}
get fc() {
  return this.createMerchantForm.controls;
}

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private countryService: CountryService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {;
    this.createCountry();
    this.loadAllCountries();
  }

  this.loadAllCountries(){
    this.countryService.getCountriesDropdown().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.countriesDatas = res.data;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    })
  }

  onCountryChange() {
    const selectedCountry = this.countriesDatas.find(
      (country) => country.countryCode === this.selectedCountryCode
    );
    this.selectedCountryName = selectedCountry
      ? selectedCountry.countryName
      : '';
  }
}

onCountrySubmitForm() {
 this.isSubmitted = true;
 if (this.createCountryForm.invalid) {
   return;
}
this.isLoading = true;
const formData = this.createCountryForm.value;

this.countryService.createCountry(formData).subscribe({
  next: (res: any) => {
    this.toastr.success(res.message);
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.event.emit('OK');
    this.onClose();
  },
 });
}
```

I want to populate the text input fields with selected CountryCode and CountryName using ng-select dropdown.

**component.html**

```
<form
  class="form-horizontal"
  id="add-form"
  [formGroup]="createCountryForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onCountrySubmitForm()"
>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Country"
    >Country:</label
  >
  <ng-select
    [items]="countriesDatas"
    [selectOnTab]="true"
    [searchable]="true"
    bindValue="CountryCode"
    bindLabel="CountryName"
    placeholder="Select Country"
    [multiple]="false"
    [clearable]="true"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCountryCode"
    (ngModelChange)="onCountryChange()"
    required
    formControlName="countryCode"
  >
  </ng-select>
          <div
            *ngIf="fc['countryCode'].touched && fc['countryCode'].invalid"
            class="alert alert-danger"
          >
            <div
              *ngIf="
                fc['countryCode'].errors &&
                fc['countryCode'].errors['required']
              "
            >
              Country Code is required!
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="divshow">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="countryName"
    id="CountryName"
    [value]="selectedCountryName"
  />
 </div>
</div>
    <button
      type="submit"
      class="btn btn-success"
      [disabled]="isLoading"
      (click)="createValidate()"
    >
      <span
        *ngIf="isLoading"
        class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"
      ></span>
      <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Actually, the ng-select dropdropdown list is passing the value of the CountryName to the text input field. I confirmed that.

But when I submitted, the backend validation, states that Country Name field is required.

So when I console.log(this.createCountry()), I got this:

```
{
    "countryCode": "235",
    "countryName": ""
}
```

I observed that the countryName is not being passed from the component.html to the component.ts.

NB: I am using Angular Reactive Form

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You have a typo on the formControlName which is case sensitive

Comment: @Johalternate - I corrected that, but the problem is still there

Comment: Any particular reason you are using ReactiveFormsModule as combined with the regular FormsModule? Right now you have `selectedCountryCode` as well as `createCountryForm`. Where is the value missing, in both of them?

Comment: @Johalternate - As I stated, the text input field for countryName is getting it's value from the ng-select dropdown. I confirmed this, and it works.    But it's not sending the value to the component.ts

Comment: Because your `createCountryForm` doesn't contain the control for  `countryName`. Thus, it will not send the value for `countryName`. Either you need to add  `countryName` control to form and assign value when `countryCode` control is changed. Or you can manually add the `countryName` property to `formData`.

Answer (score 0):

With reactive forms, you need not use 'ngModel' in form controls. Reactive forms can be subscribed for state changes as below:

```
 this.createCountryForm.controls.countryCode.valueChanges((value) => {
        const selectedCountry = this.countriesDatas.find(
          (country) => country.countryCode === value
        );
        this.createCountryForm.controls.countryName.setValue(selectedCountry?.countryName)
    })
```